# Link works in Firefox but not active in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, cross-browser, anchor

On this page: [prolitho.com/wp/about](http://www.prolitho.com/wp/about/)

If you click on the first employee picture (Mary) the image and .profile-cover will move out of the way and you will see among other things a linkedin icon.

In Firefox that icon reacts to hover and is clickable.  In Safari and Chrome it is inactive.  I can't figure out why.  Any ideas?

Comment: Poss related: in Chrome on OSX the details appear if i click on the photo, but the console reports Uncaught ReferenceError: plStaffClick is not defined www.prolitho.com/wp/about/:237 -- have you runall your JS through jshint ? There may be a JS bug which Gecko (Firefox) tolerates but webkit (Chrome/Safari) does not

Comment: plStaffClick is a remnant of some other debugging.  Removing the reference and thus the error has no effect on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the `z-index` that is being set to -1 for `profile-extra` so it's not receiving events.

One way to deal with the problem would be to set the `z-index` of `.profile-extra` to something higher than 1 while displaying the extra info

Comment: That was it.  I changed the z-index to 1 when visible and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your pulling the logo in as a fontawesome icon.

```
.fa-linkedin-square:before {
    content: "";
}
```

Chrome seems to be having issues understanding this character.

Comment: The character is showing up fine for me in Chrome and Safari.